# Bootstrap: Responsive row of equal-height images, width based on image aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I feel like I've read through about 20 or so similar posts, but none seem to have the exact thing I'm looking for.

The problem:

I have a row of images (say 3 for example). Each image has a different aspect ratio. I want to display all images in a row such that their heights are equal. The width of the column containing the images is fluid. I'm not fixing the height myself and I don't want to arbitrarily limit the height of the images. The images (and their padding) fill the horizontal space completely; this determines the height (because the aspect ratio is maintained). When the window shrinks (to mobile sizes) I want all the images to be placed one below the other like bootstrap's responsive layout usually does.

I've tried many things. I'm pretty sure that I can't use the bootstrap column classes (like col-md-4) because they change the size of their content to maintain a fixed width. As far as I can tell, bootstrap doesn't offer a clean solution to this. I've also tried table-responsive, which doesn't seem to help. Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Show some code, so anyone can inspect it.

Comment: Add some code otherwise add sketch as per your requirement.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/xAWlg Here is an image of what I'm looking for.

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/gsy21yOsi1 Here is some code, it's quite minimal, but I would expect that it's only a few lines of css away from correct. I'm not sure whether I should be using a bootstrap class and overridding some css or not. I think I would need to to keep the responsive behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```css
td img {
    height: 12vw;
    width: auto;
    margin: 4px;
}
div {
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
table {
 width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
      <img src="//placehold.it/200x150/2255EE">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/450">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/450/300">
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x400">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x200">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see that the 12vw is doing all the heavy lifting here. I was hoping for a solution where the images fill the space horizontally under the constraint that the heights are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this . whatever image you add to these three div they will always be equal in height without cutting the image.

Irepeated the loop 45 times to show end result clearly you can do this only 15 times too by increasing width-change from 0.5% to 1% in the code. (last line of for loop).

also you can make the width-change to 2% and make loop go only four rimes and then crop the extra height from the images (it won't be more then 15 to 20px or so) and you have to repeat it 4 times instead of 45.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var width = [33.33,33.33,33.33];
  for(var j=0;j<45;j++){
  var height1 = $(".imagecol").eq(0).css("height");
  var height3 = $(".imagecol").eq(1).css("height");
  var height3 = $(".imagecol").eq(2).css("height");
  var maxH=height1;
  var maxHi=0;
  var minH=height1;
  var minHi=0;
  for(var i=1;i<3;i++){
    if($(".imagecol").eq(i).css("height")>maxH){
      maxH = $(".imagecol").eq(i).css("height");
      maxHi=i;
    }
    if($(".imagecol").eq(i).css("height")<minH){
      minH = $(".imagecol").eq(i).css("height");
      minHi=i;
    }
  }
  width[maxHi] = width[maxHi]-0.25;
  width[minHi] = width[minHi]+0.25;
  $(".imagecol").eq(maxHi).css("width",(width[maxHi]+"%"))
  $(".imagecol").eq(minHi).css("width",(width[minHi]+"%"))
  }
  for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
    $(".imagecol").eq(i).css("height",minH);
  }
});
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.imagecol{
  width:33.33%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  float:left;
}
.imagerow{
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.displayIm{
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="imagerow">
 <div class="imagecol">
  <img class="displayIm" src="https://media.zigcdn.com/media/content/2016/Feb/bike-of-the-year-pulsar-rs200-m_720x540.jpg" />
 </div>
 <div class="imagecol">
  <img class="displayIm" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/50704/car-race-ferrari-racing-car-pirelli-50704.jpeg" />
 </div>
 <div class="imagecol">
  <img class="displayIm" src="http://www.iwallfinder.com/files/81/the-second-series-of-the-vertical-screen-flower-photo-40456.jpg" />
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Doesn't your resize algorithm have some pretty bad performance implications? I see you resize the image many times for each resizing of the window (up to a possible 45 times!).

Comment: 45 times is for accuracy

Comment: you can do this only 15 times too but you have to increase width-change from `0.5%` to `2%` in the code. (last line of for loop).

Comment: there are other ways to but not without cropping your image. so you have to decide the price.

Comment: also you can make the width-change to `2%` and make loop go only four rimes and then crop the extra height from the images (it won't be more then 20px or so) and you have to repeat it 4 times instead of 45

Comment: it's pretty flexible solution

Comment: An iterative solution just doesn't feel like the right approach. Everything is known up front. I'm really surprised that I haven't see some pure css way to do this.

Comment: Didn't mean to send that so soon. I was going to comment that by knowing the aspect ratios, the padding, and the container size, this can be computed in one shot. If I end up doing that in a js function I'll post the answer, but I'm still on the search for a css solution.

Comment: No, it was my bad . should have explained the code otherwise it looks bad looping 45 times. I know that

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JbVqYW Here is a similar function but without the iteration. It's still not perfect, but it will do the job in a pinch.

Comment: it's not opening. reloading in every 3 seconds, non-stoppable.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ZhrauvMb Here is the function. Not sure if it's a codepen problem or something with the code I wrote. I'm a total noob at javascript so who knows if there's something wrong with the way I'm doing things, but the math is correct for resizing the windows.

Comment: well it's essentially the same thing. I just defined my width in percentage to make it responsive, or it could be shortened further.